# Ограничения доступа к веб-сайту по стране

Tags: геолокация

Хочу оставить доступ к сайту только с определенных стран. На сколько решения могут быть эффективными и какие технологии использовать для достижения поставленной цели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть различные способы. Как вариант, использовать базы данных геосервисов и их api, которые позволяют распознать страну. Сейчас много подобных бесплатных api со своими базами.
Еще некоторые использую фильтр по языку, извлекаемому из тела запроса, но данный способ менее эффективен.